# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '['

Tags: php, syntax-error

i keep getting the error `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '['`

for some strange reason and i really cant figure out why, heres my skype.class

```
    <?php

class SkypeResolver {
    function __construct($db) {
        $this->db = new DB($db);
    }
    function get_ip($username) {
        $str = $this->skypeurl();
        $str .= $username;
        $output = file_get_contents($str);
        return $output;
    }
    function skypeurl() {
        return $this->db->fetch_array($this->db->query("SELECT * FROM `settings` WHERE `ident`='skype-api-url'"))['val'];
    }
}
?>
```

ive tried removing the "[" but it then throws another error which i fix which then leads to another error and so on... anyone got any ideas ?

Comment: Array dereferencing is supported from PHP 5.4 onwards. You need a workaround / temp var.

Answer (score 0):

Like somebody said older PHP version. You need to do it the old way.

```
function skypeurl() {
$array = $this->db->fetch_array($this->db->query("SELECT * FROM `settings` WHERE `ident`='skype-api-url'"));
return $array['val'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution:

```
function skypeurl() {
    $array = $this->db->fetch_array($this->db->query(\
        "SELECT * FROM `settings` WHERE `ident`='skype-api-url'"));
    return $array['val'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use PHP 5.4 or higher to directly get array keys from functions. 
This is a workaround working on any version:

```
function skypeurl() {
    $res = $this->db->fetch_array($this->db->query("SELECT * FROM `settings` WHERE `ident`='skype-api-url'"));
    return $res['val'];
}
```